# LINQ Equivalent for SQL BETWEEN

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Is there a LINQ To SQL equivalent to the SQL `between` keyword?

Do I just need to `And` both comparisons?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
  FROM people
 WHERE last_name between 'Smith' and 'Thompson'
```

Comment: Both answered the question, but James gets the credit for the more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean "in Linq to Sql".  Linq by itself just passes the expression to the LinqProvider which translates it into something appropriate for the data store being queried.

That being said, I'm pretty sure that the MSSQL provider used by Linq to Sql will translate `last_name >= "Smith" and last_name <= "Thomson"` into a `BETWEEN` expression.

UPDATE: Empirical evidence (via LINQPad) shows that it does not translate to `BETWEEN`

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that there is no way to do a "BETWEEN" via LINQ.  You have to do it just like you said, by ANDing your upper and lower bounds.